# Adding custom tooltip on an SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) map when mouse is hovered.

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, web

I have an SVG map of India and I want to display a customized tooltip on mouseover like this https://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=india . I have downloaded SVG map from this website but I am not able to display a tooltip when mouse is hovered over the states.
It would be great if the solution is given either using jquery or JS.

Comment: Why are you not able to? What tooltip do you want? Will a <title> child element not do?

Comment: i want an custom tooltip moreover, Idk where to put that <title> tag.

Comment: Custom in what way? as I said you make it a child element of whatever you want it to appear on.

Comment: <path> tag is not a container tag. so should i put <path> inside <span> or <g> tag?

Comment: where do I put title tag?. which tag should be the parent of <title> tag. this SVG contains a <g> tag and all the states are inside that tag, the states are defined using path tags.

Comment: The parent of the title tag would be the tag you want to display the tooltip on. In your case most likely you want a title tag as a child of each path tag.

Comment: path tag is not an container tag. it cannot have child tag.

Comment: You're correct that it is not a container tag. You're wrong that it cannot have a title child tag. Why not stop arguing and just try it?

Comment: Thanks I tried it and it worked. But now the problem is that I want to have a customised tooltip.

Comment: Which is why I asked what you meant by custom several comments ago. You'd need to roll your own for that.

Comment: @Adarsh This is a common question that has many answers on S.O. Also a simple web search will return numerous approaches you could take.